# Why I can't parse string array from JSON

Tags: webapi

I was writing a code for exchange app using my local bank api.
JSON response looks like this:

```
{"date":"01.12.2014",
"bank":"PB",
"baseCurrency":980,
"baseCurrencyLit":"UAH",
"exchangeRate[{"baseCurrency":"UAH","currency":"AUD","saleRateNB":12.8319250,"purchaseRateNB":12.8319250,{"baseCurrency":"UAH","currency":"CAD","saleRateNB":13.2107400,"purchaseRateNB":13.2107400,"saleRate":15.0000000,"purchaseRate":13.0000000},
*other currencies here in exchangeRate array*}]
```

I am using this approach

```
private static async Task ProcessExchangeRate()
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var responce = await client.GetAsync("https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/exchange_rates?json&date=01.12.2020");
        if (responce.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            ExchangeRate rate = await responce.Content.ReadAsAsync<ExchangeRate>();
        }
    }
```

ExchangeRate class

```
    [JsonPropertyName("date")]
    public string Date { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("exchangeRate")]
    public string Rates { get; set; }
```

For some reason it works for Date property, but not for Rates. What should I do?

Comment: p.s. By "not working" I mean returning null value property "Rates"

Comment: i guess because it is an array. hence it is another object and not a string. Try public string[] Rates { get; set;} instead. Maybe this could work.

Comment: No, tried already, but thx for comment

Comment: is there maybe another annotation you could use instead of JsonPropertyName? Maybe JsonObjectName or something like that?

Comment: I can use whatever is working, but my compiler can't identify the JasonObjectName

Answer (score 0):

I found out, that I should have use

```
public object[] exchangeRate { get; set; }
```

for exchangeRate, thx @Kerem for pointing me on it.